# How to retrieve TimezoneDB time to Swift Label

Tags: json, swift, timezonedb

I'm looking to display a countdown timer Label is Swift 4.0 using the time from an online database. I do not want to use the phone's time.

I originally wanted to retrieve the time from Firebase but had no luck but then I found timezonedb and made a little more progress.

I have my API key and want to know how to implement the query.

I have set my url variable to the query with my API key and used components to extract the info.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?key=YOUR_API_KEY&format=json&by=zone&zone=America/Chicago") // I inserted my API key before but left it blank here

let components = URLComponents(url: url!, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)

if let components = components {
    components.host
    components.query
    components.percentEncodedQuery

    if let queryItems = components.queryItems {
        for queryItem in queryItems {
            print("\(queryItem.name): \(queryItem.value)")
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at getting a time in hh : mm : ss but instead get this:

```
key: Optional("// My key")
format: Optional("json")
by: Optional("zone")
zone: Optional("America/Chicago")
```

Comment: The code you posted makes no attempt to actually access the URL and get a result. All it does it print the parts of the URL.

Comment: Could you show me where to start? I am new to swift, especially with anything server related

Comment: Search on `URLSession`.

Comment: Wanted to thank rmaddy for the quick responses; you helped me find exactly what I needed (which doesn't really use URLSession). It's TrueTime: https://github.com/instacart/TrueTime.swift